# Remove word from URL and redirect to resultant URL

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have a product URL withe the format

https://www.maydomain.com/proddetail.php?prod=ACME-XYZ-Golden-Widget-001

and would like to remove the word 'Golden' from all URLs such that they become

https://www.maydomain.com/proddetail.php?prod=ACME-XYZ-Widget-001

AND the old URL now redirect to the new URL.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If the replacement is restricted to query string alone, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(prod=.*)-golden-(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^proddetail\.php$ /$0?%1-%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is there a way to issue a 404 before redirect?